# Angular Material Datepicker not returning correct results with Elasticsearch Range Query

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch instances of documnts that I have indexed on local ES server based on temporal range queries that I am creating. My documents have been created from `01-03-2017` to `31-03-2017`.

HTTP request:

```
temporalsearch: temporalsearch
function temporalsearch(beginfrom, beginto) {
            console.log("hello");
            var _url = 'http://127.0.0.1:9201/_search?';
            var b = {
                "query": {
                    "range" : {
                        "metadata.o2r.temporal.begin" : {
                            "gte": beginfrom,
                            "lte": beginto
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            return $http.post(_url,b);
        }
```

Javascript:

```
function SearchController($scope,$stateParams, $q, $log, httpRequests, $location, searchResults, header, icons, leafletData) {
      var beginfrom;
      var beginto;

      var vm = this;
      $scope.beginfromDate = new Date();
      $scope.begintoDate = new Date();

      vm.beginfromDate = beginfromDate;
      vm.begintoDate = begintoDate;  

 function beginfromDate() {
     beginfrom = $scope.beginfromDate;
     console.log(JSON.stringify(beginfrom, 'bf'));
}

function begintoDate() {
    beginto = $scope.begintoDate;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(beginto,'bt'));
}
```

HTTP call in Javascript:

```
function callingtemporalsearch() {
    console.log('calling temporal search');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    httpRequests.temporalsearch(beginfrom, beginto)
                .then(cb1)
                .catch(errorHandler);

    return deferred.promise;

   function cb1(response) {
       $log.debug('result of search: %o', response);
   }

   function errorHandler(e) {
      $log.debug('search error: %o', e);
      deferred.resolve(e);
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-button ng-click="vm.Button()" class="search-button md-primary md-raised white-font">Temporal1</md-button>

    <md-datepicker ng-model='beginfromDate'ng-change="vm.beginfromDate()"></md-datepicker>
                <h4>Begin To</h4>
                  <md-datepicker ng-model='begintoDate'ng-change="vm.begintoDate()" ></md-datepicker>
```

I want to be able to stop the change directive from searching documents on default values as it returns wrong results.